# NodeMailer - SMTP Transport connection Pooling

Tags: smtpclient, nodemailer

From the following documentation : https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/  , It looks like by default the NodeMailer will not use a connection pool by default. Hence Transporter.Close() is not required unless pooling is used.

Without pooling, a new connection is used everytime the sendEmail() is called. Can someone who knows the nodemailer code clarify if the SMTP transport connection is closed automatically for every sendEmail call when pooling is not used?